# How to get the most significant bit being one in VHDL?

Tags: vhdl, binary

Say in VHDL I have an entity with as input a 8-bit vector:

```
libary ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity example is
port(
    clk : in std_logic;
    inputvector : in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
    outputvector : out std_logic_vector(2 downto 0)
);
end entity example;
```

I want to output the position of the most significant bit being one in the input vector (starting with counting from zero).

So for example if \$\text{inputvector} = [\underset{7}0,\underset{6}0,\underset{5}1,\underset{4}0,\underset{3}1,\underset{2}1,\underset{1}0,\underset{0}1]\$, the most significant bit being one is bit \$5\$. And since \$(5)_{\text{decimal}} = (101)_\text{binary}\$, the output must be \$\text{outputvector} = [1, 0,1]\$.

What do I need to write in the architecture of `example` to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

**Edit:** How I would do this in Matlab or Python (with `from numpy import ceil, log2`):

```
ceil(log2(x)) - 1
```

with `x` the inputvalue. So \$x = (101101)_\text{binary} = (45)_\text{decimal}\$ would give

```
>> ceil(log2(45)) - 1

ans =

     5
```

Comment: I can only sugget to a switch statement where you check the value of each bit starting from 7 downto 0

Comment: If you have the space, a 256-entry LUT is the fastest way to do this.

Comment: I would use an 8-bit shift register shifting to the left until you get your '1' and outputting a 3-bit counter incremented each clock cycle

Answer (score 2):

What you are asking for is called a 'Priority Encoder'. For an example, see this existing question:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14113125/short-way-to-write-vhdl-priority-encoder

Looking at that example, you would replace `switch` with your input, and assign your output using `highest_switch`.